# socket.io Can't get number of clients in room

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I am making a game and I want to create 2-user rooms, when I try to get the number of users

```
io.sockets.emit('roomUsers', io.sockets.clients(openRoom).lenght);
```

node.js crashes

This is the log I get, I have no clue what does it mean:

```
/Users/ilya/game-app-1/node_modules/socket.io/lib/parser.js:75
      data = JSON.stringify(ev);
                  ^
TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
    at Object.stringify (native)
    at Object.exports.encodePacket (/Users/ilya/game-app-1/node_modules/socket.io/lib/parser.js:75:19)
    at SocketNamespace.packet (/Users/ilya/game-app-1/node_modules/socket.io/lib/namespace.js:154:23)
    at SocketNamespace.emit (/Users/ilya/game-app-1/node_modules/socket.io/lib/namespace.js:188:15)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/Users/ilya/game-app-1/app.js:101:14)
    at Socket.EventEmitter.emit [as $emit] (events.js:96:17)
    at SocketNamespace.handlePacket (/Users/ilya/game-app-1/node_modules/socket.io/lib/namespace.js:335:22)
    at Manager.onClientMessage (/Users/ilya/game-app-1/node_modules/socket.io/lib/manager.js:488:38)
    at WebSocket.Transport.onMessage (/Users/ilya/game-app-1/node_modules/socket.io/lib/transport.js:387:20)
    at Parser.<anonymous> (/Users/ilya/game-app-1/node_modules/socket.io/lib/transports/websocket/hybi-16.js:39:10)
```

Comment: can you print out ev and share here - the content is most likely not valid JSON (you can check that on jsonlint as well)

Comment: @alihaider what is ev?

Comment: data = JSON.stringify(ev); //ev is what you are passing to JSON.stringify - can you share the contents of ev

Comment: @alihaider oh.. this is some inner function of socket.io probably, I never called it myself...

Comment: can you check your app.js file and confirm if 'ev' is not being passed by your code?  From the trace: at Socket.<anonymous> (/Users/ilya/game-app-1/app.js:101:14)

Comment: this is the line for `io.sockets.clients(openRoom).lenght`

Comment: I am assuming you mistyped length.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSON.stringify() cannot convert objects that have circular references. Whatever 'ev' is, it references itself in some way inside of itself.

DOM nodes, for example, have `ownerDocument`s, which refers to `document`. `document` ends up referencing itself through `document.body.ownerDocument`.

Answer (score 1):

It means it's trying to convert an object to json and there is a member down the tree pointing to one of it's parent. This would create an infinitely deep json file due to recursion